# NG5002 div tag already closed by another tag

Tags: html, angular

In angular component html

```
    <div>
        <label >Contrast:</label>    
        <input type="range">
    </div>
    <!-----------this code is working---->
    <div>
        <label >Contrast:</label>
        <input type="range">
        <span>100%<span>             
    </div>
    <!-----this code is giving error----->
```

[image: terminal after ng serve]

Trying to make a simple slider but error came so removed a lot of the data to check what was causing error
no error is coming even if div closing tag is removed
i did spend some time on searching the error, may be i'm dumb to not understand, i couldnt find any. even  a link to a solution would be helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your span

```
<div>
    <label >Contrast:</label>    
    <input type="range">
</div>
<!-----------this code is working-->
<!------------------------------------------------------------------>
<div>
    <label >Contrast:</label>
    <input type="range">
    <span>100%</span>             
</div>
```

Comment: but why the error says div tag is closed by another tag??

Comment: usually when you see unexpected closing tag error, the problem is with an adjacent element that hasn't been properly closed.